# how to prove that which constants a,b,c,and d it is true that f o g = g o f

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

im working on a functions unit and Im stuck on this problem:

Let $f(x) = ax + b$ and $g(x) = cx^2 + dx$ (a,b,c,d are constant). Compute f o g and g o f. And determine for which constants a, b, c and d it is true that f o g = g o f
(hint: polynomials are equal as functions if and only if they have the same coefficients)

Here's what i did: so I set f o g = g o f.

so i got : $$a(cx^2+dx)+b = c(ax+b)^2 + d(ax+b)$$$$\implies acx^2+adx+b = ca^2x^2 + 2cabx + cb^2+dax+db$$

Am I correct? what should be the remaining step? It is really confusing..

detailed explanation will be very much appreciated.. Thank you!

Comment: You're doing great.  Now, if two polynomials are equal, then the coefficients of like powers must be equal.

Comment: You haven't expanded $c(ax+b)^2$ correctly

Comment: @Mufasa I edited it. What should be the next step??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality that you have obtained is not an usual equation, like
$$2x+3=7$$
which is an equality of *numbers*. It is an equality of *polynomials*, and it can be solved equalling the coefficient of $x$ and $x^2$, and the constant term:
$$ac=ac$$
which is a trivial equality (it gives no information) and
$$ad=2bc+ad$$
$$b=2b^2c+bd$$

The first gives $bc=0$, and with the second gives $b=bd$ which is true if $b=0$ or $d=1$. Can you go on?

Comment: i think i get what you mean after thinking about it for an hour. So since I have the value for b and d, I only need a and c right? However, I edited my calculation because it was wrong. So is what you said here still valid if I edited my calculation?

Answer (score 0):

@ajotatxe has correctly described how to solve this type of problem in his answer. However, he was basing it on your earlier equation - which you have now corrected to:$$acx^2+adx+b = ca^2x^2 + 2cabx + cb^2+dax+db$$$$\therefore acx^2+adx+b = ca^2x^2 + a(2cb+d)x + b(cb+d)$$Now comparing the coefficients of each power of $x$ we get:$$ac=ca^2\tag{1}$$$$ad=a(2cb+d)\tag{2}$$$$b=b(cb+d)\tag{3}$$Solve these to determine $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$